# How to return first_name already exist when he submit with the same first_name in database

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get data from Json by first_name

This is for a Reac JS, Running in Node JS, and use Json as Web api. in the past. i've tried on how to get sepecsific data like firstname in jsoon-server to make function if first name already exist it will return false

BlogPost.js

```js
import React, {Component,Fragment} from 'react';
import './BlogPost.css';
import Post from '../../Component/Post/Post';
import axios from 'axios';


class BlogPost extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            errors : [],
            post : [],
            formData : {
                id : '',
                first_name : '',
                last_name : '',
                email : '',
                confirmFirst : '',
                usernameValid : false,
                formValid : false
            }, 
            isUpdate : false,


        }
    }


    getPostAPI = () => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8001/employees/')
        .then((res) => {
            this.setState ({
                post : res.data
            })
        })
    }

    sendPostAPI = () => {
        axios.post('http://localhost:8001/employees', this.state.formData).then ((res) => {
            console.log(res) 
            this.getPostAPI();
            this.setState ({
                formData : {
                    id :'',
                    first_name : '',
                    last_name : '',
                    email : ''
                },
            })
        }, (err) => {
            console.log('error : ', err);
        })
    }

    putDataToAPI = () => {
        axios.put(`http://localhost:8001/employees/${this.state.formData.id}`,this.state.formData).then (res => {          
            console.log(res);
            this.getPostAPI();
            this.setState ({
                isUpdate : false,
                formData : {
                    id : '',
                    first_name : '',
                    last_name : '',
                    email : ''
                },
            })
        })
    }

    handleUpdate = (data) => {
        console.log(data)
        this.setState({
            formData : data,
            isUpdate : true

        })

    }

    handleRemove = (data) => {
        console.log(data)
        axios.delete(`http://localhost:8001/employees/${data}`).then (res => {
            this.getPostAPI();
            console.log(res);
        })
    }

    handleFormChange = (event) => {
            let formDataNew = {...this.state.formData};
            let timeStamp = new Date().getTime();
            if (!this.state.isUpdate) {
                formDataNew['id'] = this.state.id + 1;
            }
            formDataNew[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
            this.setState ({
                formData : formDataNew
            })
    }

    handleEmpty = () => {
        if ((this.state.formData['first_name'] === "") || (this.state.formData['last_name'] === "") || (this.state.formData['email'] === "")) {
            alert("Semua Data Harus Di Isi!!!");  
        }else     
        if (this.state.formData['email'].split("").filter(x => x === "@").length !== 1) {
            alert("Email should contain a @");
        }
    }

    handleEmailChange(e) {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        if (this.state.formData.first_name.indexOf(value) !== -1) {
          this.setState({
            error: true,
            errorMessage: "Email already subscribed"
          })
        } else {
          this.setState({
            [name]: value
          });
        }
      }



    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        const { first_name, confirmFirst} = this.state.formData;
        if (this.state.isUpdate) { 
            if ((this.state.formData['first_name'] === "") || (this.state.formData['last_name'] === "") || (this.state.formData['email'] === "")) {
                alert("Semua Data Harus Di Isi!!!");
                this.setState ({
                    formData : {
                        id :'',
                        first_name : '',
                        last_name : '',
                        email : ''
                    },
                })

            }else     
            if (this.state.formData['email'].split("").filter(x => x === "@").length !== 1) {
                alert("Email should contain a @");
                this.setState ({
                    formData : {
                        id :'',
                        first_name : '',
                        last_name : '',
                        email : ''
                    },
                })
            }else {
                this.putDataToAPI();
            }     

        } else {
            if ((this.state.formData['first_name'] === "") || (this.state.formData['last_name'] === "") || (this.state.formData['email'] === "")) {
                alert("Semua Data Harus Di Isi!!!");  
              }else  
            if (this.state.formData['email'].split("").filter(x => x === "@").length !== 1) {
                alert("Email Harus menggunakan '@' ");
              }else 
            if (this.props.data === this.state.formData.first_name) {
                 alert('Username sudah digunakan')
            } else {
                    console.log(this.props.data);
                    this.sendPostAPI();

                }
            }
        }


    handleBatal = () => {
        this.setState ({
            isUpdate : false,
            formData : {
                id : '',
                first_name : '',
                last_name : '',
                email : ''
            }

        })
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        this.getPostAPI();
        // this.sendPostAPI();
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <Fragment>
            <p className="section-title">Blog Post</p>
            <div className="form-add-post">
                <label htmlFor="id">ID</label>
                <input type="number" value={this.state.formData.id} name="id" placeholder="Id" disabled/>

                <label htmlFor="first_name">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" value={this.state.formData.first_name} name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" onChange={this.handleFormChange}  required />

                <label htmlFor="last_name">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" value={this.state.formData.last_name} name="last_name" required="Sorry, This Field cannot Empty" placeholder="Last Name"  onChange={this.handleFormChange}  required />

                <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" value={this.state.formData.email} name="email" required="Sorry, This Field cannot Empty" placeholder="Email"  onChange={this.handleFormChange}  required />

                <button className="btn-submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Simpan</button>
                <button className="btn-batal" onClick={this.handleBatal}>Batal</button>


            </div>
            {
                this.state.post.map(post => {
                    return <Post key= {post.id} data = {post} remove={this.handleRemove} update={this.handleUpdate}/>
                })
            }

            </Fragment>
        )

    }
}


export default BlogPost;
```

Post.js

```js
import React from 'react';

const Post = (props) => {

    return (
        <div className="post">
                    <div className="img-thumb">
                        <img src="http://placeimg.com/200/150/tech" alt="dummy"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="content">
                        <p className="title">Nama : {props.data.first_name + ' ' + props.data.last_name}</p>
                        <p className="desc">Email : {props.data.email}</p>
                        <button className="remove" onClick= {() => props.remove(props.data.id)} >Remove</button>
                        <button className="update" onClick= {() => props.update(props.data)} >Update</button>
                    </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Post;
```

db.json

```
{
  "employees": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "first_name": "Fernando",
      "last_name": "Alexsandro",
      "email": "volcomzxy@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "first_name": "Alexsandros",
      "last_name": "Palmer",
      "email": "volcomzxy@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "first_name": "Siregar",
      "last_name": "Siagian",
      "email": "volcomzxy@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "first_name": "Miracle",
      "last_name": "AF",
      "email": "volcomzxy@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "first_name": "NoMercy",
      "last_name": "389",
      "email": "volcomzxy@gmail.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

i expect the output will false when we submit with same firstname/lastname/email with database will return false, and my exactly question is how to get firstname from json data. thank you

Comment: One idea is, when you have all the data in `post` state variable, before submitting you can check in `this.state.post` that if that record is already present or not. If present don't send request to add at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take this as a very simple application and not applicable in production.

```
    sendPostAPI = () => {
        const { post, formData } = this.state
        if (post.find(e => e.email === formData.email || `${e.first_name}${e.last_name}` === `${formData.first_name}${formData.last_name}`)){
          return false
        }
        axios.post('http://localhost:8001/employees', formData).then ((res) => {
            console.log(res) 
            this.getPostAPI();
            this.setState ({
                formData : {
                    id :'',
                    first_name : '',
                    last_name : '',
                    email : ''
                },
            })
        }, (err) => {
            console.log('error : ', err);
        })
    }
```

I think you are missing the idea that you already have access to the list data in `post` variable since you triggered are request in `componentDidMount`